# issues showing both "return" button and "done" button in "TextInput"

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput

Problem:
Using "TextInput" in react native shows keyboard, and on pressing return, cursor moves to new line, however at this i do not have "done" button to hide the keyboard.

Again, there is props called "returnKeyType={done}, which adds "done" button but now "return" button is gone. I believe user could tap to new line inside "TextInput" box, but it seems to highlight the words typed.

Solution attempt:
Like in numeric keyboard, i thought there should be some props to add "done" button on top of keyboard so that we will have both "return" and "done" botton visible at the same time, but i could not find it.

... another option is i could create my own component with done button, and wrap keyboard as child, but i could not figure out how i do it.

This is basic component, i believe there must be some elegant way to do it. any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you please share code of textinput you did?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have done and newline button at the same time.
There should only be one submitting button in keyboard.

But you can make a similar work around.

### Custom Button

First option is making custom button like you mentioned.
Make a "Done" button next to your textfield or above the keyboard.

### onSubmitEdit

Second option is using [onSubmitEdit](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting)

Make a custom function that controls what return button should do.

e.g.)

```
const [textInputValue, setTextInputValue] = useState("");

const returnPressed = () => {
    if(need_new_line){
        setTextInputValue(textInputValue+"\n");
    } else {
        returnFunction();
    }
};

return (
    <TextInput
        value={textInputValue}
        onChangeText={(text)=> setTextInputValue(text)}
        onSubmitEditing={()=> returnPressed()}
    />
);
```

Comment: on your suggested "onSubmitEdit" 
... when user press "return" key, it will run "returnPressed" function. Now how do i know & track if user is trying to return or add a new line. 

To reiterate, my intent is to allow both functionality.